# Unable to run local bot on Bot Framework emulator

Tags: macos, botframework, emulation

i am new at using Bot Framework Emulator and trying to run Echo bot. I am successful running the bot locally. But when I try to use Bot Framework Emulator to test. It doesnt seem to be listening to the host and port i inputted. Any idea? thank you≥
running this on mac.
visual studio 2019
emulator: 4.9.0-140906

```
[17:55:35]Connecting to bot on http://localhost:3978/api/messages
[17:55:35]Emulator listening on http://[::]:52655
[17:55:35]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely hosted bots)
[17:55:35]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[17:55:35]Edit ngrok settings
[17:55:35]Cannot post activity. Unauthorized.
```

Comment: As mentioned below, you will need to double-check if you have added the appID and password in your appsettings.json. If yes, then you need to add the app Id and password in the emulator settings as well when you select the 'Open Bot' option along with the Bot URL. For testing the bot locally, you can leave the credentials blank at both places. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#use-bot-credentials

Answer (score 2):

Did you register a value for **Microsoft App ID** and **Microsoft App password** in the emulator settings? This setting is optional, however if you configured them in your **appsettings.json** you will need to provide the corresponding values also in the emulator.

For testing locally however, you can leave the **MicrosoftAppId** and **MicrosoftAppPassword** as blank in the **appsettings.json**.